# toggleClass on function

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is two buttons on same photo, 1 for delete and second for top photo. When I click on top icon this active all elements, I want when I click on top icon change class on chosen and previous delete active class.

How can I using toggleClass on this function.

```
echo "<div class=\"photo-cp\">";
echo "<a id=\"".$data['pid']."\" onclick=\"photo_top(this);\" class=\"top-photo\"></a>\n";
echo "<a id=\"".$data['pid']."\" onclick=\"photo_delete(this);\" class=\"remove-photo rounded\"></a>";
echo "</div>\n";
```

CSS

```
.photo-cp {position:absolute; top:5px; right:5px; width:42px; height:26px; display:block;}
.photo-cp a {float:left; margin:4px 0 0 4px;}
.remove-photo {background: url("../images/remove.png") no-repeat 0 0; width:16px; height:16px;   display:block; cursor:pointer}
.top-photo {width:16px; height:16px; display:block; cursor:pointer}
.top-photo {background: url("../images/star.png") no-repeat 0 0;}
.top-photo.active { background: url("../images/star.png") no-repeat 0 -16px; }
```

Jquery

```
 function photo_top(obj){
   var pid = obj.id;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "jq-photos.php",
  data: { pid: pid },
  dataType: "json",
  beforeSend: function() {
  },
  success: function(obj) {
        if (obj.error == false) {
            $(".top-photo").toggleClass('active').sibling().removeClass('active');
                } else {
            alert("Error!");
        }
    }
});
return false;
```

}

Comment: **Typo?** `sibling()` should be `siblings()`

Comment: yes but active all other elements with class top-photo